# What is the highest version of Bobo-Browse that is compatible with Lucene 3.0.3?

Tags: java, lucene, lucene.net, bobo-browse.net

...or maybe this question could be shortened to - are Bobo-Browse and Lucene using [semantic versioning](http://semver.org/)?

I am contributing NuGet build script to a [.NET port](https://github.com/zhengchun/Bobo-Browse.Net) of the Java [Bobo-Browse](https://github.com/javasoze/bobo/releases) faceted search engine, which has been upgraded to be compatible with [Lucene.Net 3.0.3](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Lucene.Net) (the latest version currently available). However, I don't know what version of Bobo-Browse this is technically a port of. The source files don't resemble the Java versions very much.

I went through the Java source files and noticed that the version numbers don't line up between Bobo-Browse and Lucene. That is, [Bobo-Browse 3.0.0 depends on Lucene 3.5.0](https://github.com/javasoze/bobo/blob/c3bedcc9157e753a6a298ebdbda1904a5d277cf8/bobo-browse/pom.xml). I tried going back further, but I can't seem to find any version numbers in the source. I then tried doing a Google search and found 2 documents [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/bobo-browse/_GihK_faJR8/1WY_W5q8ceoJ) and [here](http://www.apstrlp.net/liferay/lib/versions.xml) that both agree that version [2.5.0 of Bobo-Browse](https://github.com/javasoze/bobo/releases) is compatible with Lucene 3.0.3.

My question is: Does that mean [version 2.5.1 of Bobo-Browse](https://github.com/javasoze/bobo/releases) is also compatible with Lucene 3.0.3? Would Bobo-Browse 3.0.0 or 3.0.1 or another higher version be compatible with Lucene 3.0.3?

**Some Context**

Actually, the port was originally done on the Lucene.Net 2.9.4 version by one developer (but given the mysterious version number 1.1.0.0 in the source files, and never officially "released") and then upgraded to Lucene.Net 3.0.3 by another developer, and there is no information about what version number this is supposed to be (and believe me, I have asked). So, this question is really to help get to the bottom of 2 different issues:

1. What version number should we give this release Bobo-Browse.Net?
2. What version of Bobo-Browse should we be porting over the unit tests from in order to better confirm that it works like that version?

The thing is - the port seems to work fine. But it doesn't seem right to either guess what version number this is supposed to be or stick 3.0.3 on it just because that is the version of Lucene.Net it is compatible with. It really *should* line up with the Bobo-Browse version in some logical way, but I need more information to be sure of what we are doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After quite a bit of research I concluded that:

1. Lucene and Bobo-Browse are using semantic versioning.
2. The major version of Bobo-Browse normally aligns with the major version of Lucene.
3. The highest version of Bobo-Browse that is compatible with Lucene 3.0.3 is Bobo-Browse 3.2.0.